# Using Illustrator CC when I insert a vector flag into a vector eagle shape it fails constantly

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to insert a vector, spot color flag into a vector, 1 color eagle. I have ungrouped and released all clipping masks and compound masks in both objects but my results are always a 1 color object. I made the eagle black so you can see what I am working with. As you can see the eagle does have 3 elements separate from the wing. I tried with these ungrouped as well as simply removing them. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: eagle-flag]

Answer (score 3):

The eagle will need to be just one object so select all the separate eagle parts and go Object> Compound Path> Make.

Also the flag elements should be grouped into a single group.

Make sure the eagle compound path is above the flag group in the stacking order.

Select both the eagle and the flag and go Object> Clipping Mask> Make.

Comment: oops- thanks for the edit @ Vincent- :)